# Tomcat NioEndpoint - Error running socket processor

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, runtime-error

In a Spring Boot production app, the following exception is occasionally thrown:

```
o.a.t.u.n.NioEndpoint : Error running socket processor

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
        at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:148) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T13ServerHelloProducer.produce(ServerHello.java:547) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:436) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1234) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1170) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:852) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:813) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1048) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:995) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.tasks(SecureNioChannel.java:443) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:507) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:238) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1616) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

It is hard to tell what causes the exception, as there are no logs before or after by the same thread. Looking at the stack-trace, it might occur before any custom request pre-processing code is reached, during the SSL handshake, which might be the reason there are no logs before. (Production application is currently logging on level TRACE.)

What could be the cause and how to fix it?

Spring Boot version: 2.2.5.RELEASE

**EDIT:**

I recently encountered a very similar case, but the stacktrace is quite different:

```
o.a.t.u.n.NioEndpoint : Error running socket processor

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at sun.security.ssl.HKDF.extract(HKDF.java:93) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.HKDF.extract(HKDF.java:119) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello.setUpPskKD(ServerHello.java:1167) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T13ServerHelloProducer.produce(ServerHello.java:545) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:436) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1234) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1170) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:852) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:813) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1048) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:995) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.tasks(SecureNioChannel.java:443) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:507) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:238) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1616) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be caused by a JRE issue:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/01d8eae542ff

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8218889

It was fixed with

- 11.0.8 b01
- 11.0.7 b04
- 8u261 b05

Are you using an affected JRE version?

As for the second issue you mentioned:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8241248

This is an option issue (but mentions a workaround).

Please look into both issues, try to update for addressing the first issue and see if your can apply the workaround as long as no fix is available for the second issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Please see the edited question: I added a **different stacktrace** which occurs similarly - out of nowhere. Do you think it is related to the exact same fix?

Comment: The issue might be related from a technical POV (potentially some kind of race condition), but I don't think the fix addresses this. The engineer responsible for the fix seems to have looked into this issue already, without mentioning the other fix. The issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8241248

Comment: I think, at this point, I cannot add to the answer without actually fixing the issue myself :) If the answer helped and you agree with the info I collected, please consider accepting it.